# Simplify a date in a Dataframe

Tags: python, django, pandas

I'm currently working on a dataframe that has a subscription date for every members. I would like to stats subscriptions per months but default behavior would counts each dates of every month separately.

I found a way of doing it modifying the date with slices and setting every dates day on 01 but i would rather use something that's made by pandas.

Any suggestion on where i should head to ?

Comment: Are you using datetime? Couldn't you slice my .month and .year? If you could give a toy example of what you have that would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for not answering your questions. I've found a solution. No i wasn't able to use .month nor .year. I decided to change date to first day of each month using a lamdba function that calls replace(day=1). Bad thing here is that i've to alter the database.

Comment: Um, Jon Clements accepted answer uses .month and .year :), you definitely don't want to be changing the way the (correct) day arbitrarily to the 1st to do this.

Comment: Well i would prefer not to but .month and .year simply throw an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your subscription date is a `datetime.datetime` instance, then you could use (untested) something like (where `df` is your `DataFrame`):

```
df.groupby(lambda L: (L.year, L.month))
```

You'll need to adjust the groupby if the datetime isn't your DataFrame's index.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

Let`s create a series that hold the member id and date of subscription.

```
In [21]: s = pandas.Series(range(100), pandas.date_range('2010-10-10', periods=100))
```

Group by year and month, count number of subscriptions per (Year/Month) combination.

```
In [22]: grouped = s.groupby([s.index.year, s.index.month])

In [23]: nr_subscriptions = grouped.count()

In [24]: nr_subscriptions.index.names = ['Year', 'Month']

In [25]: nr_subscriptions.names = 'nr_subscriptions'

In [26]: nr_subscriptions
Out[26]: 
Year  Month
2010  10       22
      11       30
      12       31
2011  1        17
```

Comment: Thanks, i used a lamdba function to state each date on day 1 using replace()